# Logstash Grok Pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to logstash and trying to custom GROK one log file could some one please guide me on how to custom grok this log.

Log entry:

`configmgr.service.configservice - revoke_app_config - Revoking config for app`

I want to grok it in such a way that it should populate the below fields as:

`PROGMODULE = configmgr.service.configservice
PROGBLOCK = revoke_app_config 
ACTION = Revoking config for app`

Comment: Please guide me on how to write the custom grok

Comment: Please fallow the answer which was given by `aairey`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like below?

```
%{NOTSPACE:PROGMODULE} - %{WORD:PROGBLOCK} - %{GREEDYDATA:ACTION}
```

Comment: %{WORD:ACTION} would only match "Revoking".  Try %{GREEYDATA:ACTION} at the end.

Comment: It's GREEDYDATA, but you are correct :) I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Ha.  I *always* misspell that!  Too bad SO won't let me edit my comment.